# That theatre ... to close down soon

Tags: grammar

Please help me choose the correct answer for:

> **That theatre ... to close down soon.
>
>   a) is thought      b) is thinking    c) thinks     d) thought**

I'd like to choose (b) because it means to me that 'that theatre wants to stop its activities soon' but the answer is (a).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why this question have to be closed. It's very clear that this question is in need of help in English grammar. Maybe a grammar book or an English teacher has the answer but the poster came here for help. What's this place for?

Comment: If you have been told that **a** is correct you are misinformed. *X is thought to be Y* is only possible if Y is a present state. "This theatre is thought to **be closing** soon" is possible, or "This theatre is **expected** to close soon", but not "This theatre is thought to close soon". I think this is why the question was closed: there is no correct answer here.

Comment: @StoneyaB I would like to get an answer like yours if I were this poster. Closing it doesn't help the poster in any way.

Answer (score 1):

All the following are correct, they just have slightly different meanings:

> A. The theatre **is thought to be** closing down soon - (The public rumour the theatre is going to close)
>
> B. The theatre **is thinking about** closing down soon - (The owners of the theatre are considering closing the theatre)
>
> C. The theatre **wants to** close down soon  - (The owners of the theatre want to close it)
>
> D. The theatre **is** closing down soon - (The theatre is certainly closing)

It is just a case of which stage of the closing down process it is so that it conveys the correct message. ***The sentence that most closely relates to your needs would probably be c, because it has not closed down yet, but it wants to.***

Therefore, in this case, the best phrase would be:

> *That theatre wants to close down soon*

Comment: There is no right answer in the provided options then?

Comment: You could use the word "wants" or "is", but if you want to use "thinking" or "thought", you need to carefully consider the tense and meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The best of all might be the very simple "That theatre is to close down soon".

However in answer to your specific question, most English teachers would consider all four of the alternatives you propose to be incorrect.